# Install Tor Browser for all users

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I'm trying to install the Tor Browser for all users on a Linux system (installed via the standalone archive from torproject.org), and having issues - it seems that Tor Browser assumes it has write access to the directory that it's installed in, and tries saving caches there. This fails whenever any other user besides myself tries to run the browser because I've only given read/execute permissions to other users. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you describe how you installed the Tor Browser for all users? Did you put it in one directory and gave users access to it or how exactlky did you do it?

Comment: That's right - I just extracted the directory from the archive and marked all of the files o+rX (readable and, for those that need to be, executable)